# Advantage of @property assuming I only need to get the value

Tags: python, class, properties

I have read a lot about the advantages of `@property`, and I really like them. As a short example

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo_value = 'foo_value'

    @property
    def foo_value(self):
        return self._foo_value


my_foo = Foo()
print(my_foo.foo_value)
```

However, *assuming* I know that I don't want do fancy stuff and only get the value of `Foo.foo_value`, I can achieve the same behavior with less code by ignoring `@property`, e.g.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo_value = 'foo_value'


my_foo = Foo()
print(my_foo.foo_value)
```

Is there any advantage of still using the `@property` in such a case?

Comment: You open the question with "I think I know all the advantages of @property" and then ask "Is there any advantage of using the @property in such a case?", which leaves me very confused as to what you're asking. No, there is no advantage in your case because it doesn't require any of the "advantages" of using `@property`

Comment: Other languages implement "getters" and "setters". You don't _need_ them in Python - `@property` is there if you need to ensure some other logic runs when getting or setting a parameter

Comment: Yeah - I see your point, I will edit the question to not cause further confusion. I meant that I have basically read a lot about and used @property a few time know, but all examples I was able to find on the internet didn't cover this specific use-case. Anyway, your response answers my question, so thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is absolutely no use for a `property` here. The *entire point* of `property` is to *avoid boilerplate* and maintain encapsulation.

#### A Pythonic class definition

Suppose you write a class:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
```

Great. Now, there's a bunch of client code out there like:

```
print(f"The radius is {some_circle.radius}")
```

#### An un-Pythonic class definition

Suppose, however, you want to make sure the radius is never set to a value below 0. Oh no! What should we do? The philosophy in languages like Java is that you should have written boilerplate getters and setters like this in the first place:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.set_radius(radius)
    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius
    def set_radius(self, radius):
        self._radius = radius
```

Then, all the client code would have been written like:

```
print(f"The radius is {some_circle.get_radius()}")
```

And we can just modify `set_radius` to throw an appropriate error:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.set_radius(radius)
    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius
    def set_radius(self, radius):
        if radius < 0:
            raise ValueError("Radius must be positive")
        self._radius = radius
```

All that boilerplate at the beginning was *worth it* because now we can make changes to the way we control access to our internal state without breaking client code.

*But this isn't Java, this is Python*

In Python, if *and when* we decide to control access, we can refactor our class *without breaking client code!*:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius
    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        if radius < 0:
            raise ValueError("Radius must be positive")
        self._radius = radius
```

Because let's be honest. Most of the time we'd rather write a class like the first example, not the second example with the pre-emptive boilerplate getters and setters, and we like to write client code like:

```
pi * circle.radius**2
```

instead of

```
pi * circle.get_radius()**2
```

In Python, we can have our cake and eat it too.

#### An exception

There is *one* use case for a `property` like in your code: we want to let the clients of our class *retrieve a value* but **not** set the value. So just like your example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._foo_value = 'foo_value'
...     @property
...     def foo_value(self):
...         return self._foo_value
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.foo_value
'foo_value'
>>> foo.foo_value = 'something else'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

If he above is the behavior you want, the the `property` is actually serving a purpose. Of course, this can be easily circumvented, but it does prevent "accidental" misuse of the API. And, we still get to keep the nicer-looking `foo.foo_value` instead of the uglier `foo.get_foo_value()`

Comment: Isn't there an error in your code
```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
```
Shouldn't it be `self._radius = radius` instead?

Comment: @KimMens no, it shouldn't. I want the setter to be called in `__init__` as well so it is equivalent to `self.set_radius(radius)`

Comment: @KimMens again this is the whole point of `property`, I'm not changing any client code, even internally, all I do is define my property *if and when I need to*, and the code I've already written "just works"

Comment: so it is _because_ you use a property decorator that you want to write self.radius = radius so that it calls the @radius.setter transparently

Comment: @KimMens yes, and to demonstrate how the actual refactor would occur

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage. If anything, you are just creating baggage for yourself.

Other languages (e.g. Java) implement "getters" and "setters" and have things like `private` variables. There is no such thing as a `private` variable in Python; you could use a leading `_` to *indicate* that a name is private, or even use `__` for "name mangling" (but that still won't stop a determined user).

There are times that `@property` does have some great utility. An uncontrived example is in the config class of one of my wrapper libraries. I know that a value outside of `0` to `1` is going to crash another API call, so I try to stop users from getting in a confusing mess if that call would blow up. I can't actually stop them doing it anyway, but I can try make the API warn them.

(Side note; I don't suggest that function names should be in CAPS but that's actually the name of some Java attributes that the API call will set, so it's for consistency)

```
    @property
    def CLUSTER_REGRET(self):
        return self._CLUSTER_REGRET

    @CLUSTER_REGRET.setter
    def CLUSTER_REGRET(self, value):
        if not 0 <= value <= 1:
            raise ValueError("CLUSTER_REGRET must be between 0 and 1")
        self._CLUSTER_REGRET = value
```