# What is the difference between explicit attribute vs @Property?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I started dealing with inheritance in Python but it was easy to inherit functions from other classes.
@Properties was easy to create but I found that it won't inherit except,

- if I follow this website:
  https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-music/-/snippets/31 .I believe it is
  complicated and it is not worth typing a lot of rows.

Later I realized that I could use **explicit attributes**  {geo_color = "green"} . Now, I am not sure what is the right way.

What is the difference between Explicit attribute vs @Property in Python?

```
import Rhino
import scriptcontext
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs

class Geometry(object):
    # Explicit attribute:
    geo_color = "green"
    # Property:
    @property 
    def color(self): 
        return self._color
    @color.setter
    def color(self, value):
        self._color = value
#
class Line(Geometry):
    def Draw(self, Point1, Point2):
        # draw line ...
        pass

line = Line()
line.geo_color = "white"
color = line.geo_color
print line.geo_color
print color
```

Comment: By the way, Python2 is end of life, and you should upgrade

Comment: Your `geo_color` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute, so `line.geo_color` should actually be `Geometry.geo_color`... Where are you actually trying to use the `_color` attribute?

Comment: `color` should absolutely not be a `property` but just a regular attribute, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67658208/5014455) for when and why you should use a `property`

Comment: Also, `property` *will absolutely be inherited*. So it isn't clear what the problem you are encountering is anyway